# Sonar-Eclipse Plugin, Sonar-Eclipse(OEPE)-Helios Integration

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, eclipse-3.6

I am trying to integrate eclipse(OEPE)-Helios with sonar but got failure all the time.
i am doing this by downloading sonar-eclipse plugin via Help --> install New Softwares feature of eclipse ide.
but always it through below error..

"could not find http://dist.sonar-ide.codehaus.org/eclipse/"

can anybody guide me to do this activity?
OR
am i doing it right way?
OR
is it possible to integrate sonar with eclipse(OEPE)-Helios?

Answer (score 1):

This URL is perfectly valid and reachable, you shouldn't have any problems.

You're probably behind a firewall, and need to configure Eclipse to use a proxy ("Eclipse Preferences > General > Network connections").

Comment: can you please elaborate it,i do not understand the concept. but when i integrate sonar with eclipse(oepe)-indigo, i do not face any problem like this and it gets integrated.

Comment: What I mean is that this is a connection problem, as the URL is perfectly valid. Sonar Ecipse is compatible for Eclipse versions >= 3.5 (Gallio), so you shouldn't have any troubles to install it. You may have some special settings on your Indigo install that allows Eclipse to connect to the remote website, whereas this is probably not the case for your Helios install.